# How to control the default music player from android wear App

Tags: wear-os, android-music-player

Hi I need to play music from my android wear app.

I use this code to open my default music player

```
          if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=15){
            Intent intent=Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,
                    Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);//Min SDK 15
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_RUN);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

But i need to implement onplay,next, previ, stop..

Searched some services too its not working..

Is any other way to play songs from android wear 
 can anyone help me to finish this.